# Access element of Point3f

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have a Point3f and I want to normalize it, e.g. divide with the last (z) element.

```
Point3f C_tmp;
```

I can print it out like this,

```
cout << "C_tmp= " << C_tmp << endl;
```

But, I cannot just do

```
C_tmp=C_tmp/C_tmp[3];
```

I use C++ interface.
I couldn't find something helpful in the documentation.
Any idea?

EDIT: Vector case:

```
int i;
    for (i=begin; i<end; i++) {
    threeD=...[i]..;
    threeDVector.push_back(threeD);
    twoD.x= threeD.x / threeD.z;
    twoD.y= threeD.y / threeD.z;
    twoDVector.push_back(twoD);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Point3f` has the fields `x`, `y`, and `z`:

```
Point3f threeD(2, 3, 4);
Point2f twoD(threeD.x / threeD.z, threeD.y / threeD.z);
```

You can also (implicitly) convert a `Point3f` to a `Vec3f` and do the trick your way (be away, c++ uses 0-based array):

```
...
Vec3f threeDVector = threeD;
threeDVector /= threeDVector[2];
```

Last, I think the best way to explore the functionality of such structures is simply just to read the opencv header files (in this case `opencv2/core/types.hpp`)

Comment: Nice approach. Now, I can access each of the x,y,z elements. However, while dividing with z value, somehow I always get 0 for y and wrong values for x (for Point2f twoD). But cout << "threeD.x= " << threeD.x << " threeD.y= " << threeD.y << " threeD.z= " << threeD.z <<endl; prints out the correct values. Why does this happen?

Comment: I found it out. If I write it so: Point2f twoD; twoD.x= threeD.x / threeD.z; twoD.y= threeD.y / threeD.z; everything is fine! Strange, huh?

Comment: @Ellie: using `cout`, the print out of `twoD` and `threeDVector` on my computer are respectively `[0.5, 0.75]` and `[0.5, 0.75, 1]`, which seem correct to me. Are you sure you're performing a floating-point calculation, rather than an integer calculation? You could potentially add a cast: `Point2f twoD((float)threeD.x / threeD.z, (float)threeD.y / threeD.z)`

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works both ways. But lets say I have many values and I store them all in a vector called threeDVector like in the loop in the edited question. Then, why the next two lines that try to create a twoDVector out of threeDVector do not work?

Comment: I solved the problem. The edited version in the vector case works fine for me. Thanks!